# why my htaccess rule not works

Tags: php, .htaccess

I created a htaccess rule but it doesnot works.
here is my url

```
http://localhost/mat/site/brandlisting/21/page/2
```

here is my htaccess rule for it

```
RewriteRule brandlisting/(.*)(.*)/page/(.*) site/brandlisting?id=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule brandlisting/(.*)(.*)/page site/brandlisting?id=$1&page=$2 [L]

RewriteRule brandlisting/(.*)/ site/brandlisting?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule brandlisting/(.*) site/brandlisting?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule site/brandlisting/(.*)/?$ site/brandlisting?id=$1 [L]
```

is there anything wrong? 
what mistate is in my htaccess rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using wildcard greedy pattern regex matching everything in single hit, use below rules I am assuming you are using .htaccess in site folder.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^brandlisting/([\d]+)/page/([\d]+)$ brandlisting?id=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^brandlisting/([\d]+)/?$ brandlisting?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^site/brandlisting/([\d]+)/?$ brandlisting?id=$1 [L]
```